# Knights and knaves gathering

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> The 16 inhabitants of Knightsland are either knights or knaves (always tell the truth or always lie). 
>   Some, or all of them, meet every Sunday at the local restaurant and sit around a circular table, in equal distances from each other, in order to discuss their pending matters and then have lunch.
>   Not all of them are always present. Also in the current meeting, not everyone was present. 
>   Jason, who is impatient and always in a hurry to finish things off and start eating, says: “We are already 11, so let’s start”. Harry, who was sitting right opposite to him, says: “No, we are not 11, we are 12 – apparently you don’t know how to count!!” The two of them were just about to start fighting but were calmed down by their left and right neighbors. Brandon, who was sitting calmly, says: “Calm down gentlemen; there were times in the past when we were even fewer! In fact, our today’s number is a product of two numbers, of which the smaller is the number we were in our smallest meeting!”
>   Finally their gathering went out of control and any of the present members was blaming his adjacent neighbors for being liars.
>   How many Knightslanders were gathered this time and what is the smallest number that they ever in the past?

I understand we have 3 statements that can be either true or false, so we have to make a truth table.

The only thing I managed to deduce is that since Harry is sitting opposite to Jason, their current number is even. Furthermore, since Harry and Jason were calmed down by their right and left neighbors, assuming these are different for each, their current number is minimum 6. 
If Brandon was sitting calmly, can we also assume he was not one of the neighbors (who were trying to calm down the others)?

Anyway, I don't know how to continue... logic is not my favorite topic!

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think you are missing an important cue: "Finally their gathering went out of control and any of the present members was blaming his adjacent neighbors for being liars." No knight would blame a neighboring knight to be a liar and no knave would blame another knave. So there are sitting alternatingly knight and knave.

Comment: Also, Jason and Harry must be of opposite kinds (if one is a knight, the other must be Knave). But I am not sure... They may both be knaves.

Comment: guarague: I am not sure about this - why can't a knave blame another knave?

Comment: I just made an edit to make it more clear that not everyone was present (so 16 is excluded). Sorry if it was not clear from the beginning.

Comment: @WangXiuYingZhang: If a knave says to another knave, "you're a knave", then that accusation would be _true_ -- and knaves cannot speak truth!

Answer (score 1):

An important observations from @quarague in comments:

> I think you are missing an important cue: "Finally their gathering went out of control and any of the present members was blaming his adjacent neighbors for being liars." No knight would blame a neighboring knight to be a liar and no knave would blame another knave. So there are sitting alternatingly knight and knave.

This implies the number of people must be **even**.

If the number is 2 modulo 4, then one of Harry and Jason is a knight and the other is a knave. But that is impossible since each of them claims a number that is not 2 modulo 4.

So the number is **a multiple of 4**, which means that Harry and Jason are of the same kind. But as they disagree, both of them are knaves. This means that **there are not 12**.

**4 itself is impossible**, as the OP notes, because then there would be no room for Brandon to be calm.

This leaves 8 and 16. But both of those appear to be possible:

- There might be 8, if Brandon is a knave (the 4 knights are busy calming down Jason and Harry) which means that "we have been even fewer" is a lie, so 8 is the fewest they have ever been. (This also makes Brandon's *second* statement a lie because 8 is indeed not a product of two numbers *the smaller of which is 8*).
- If there are 16, then Brandon must be a knight because he says "we have been even fewer" which we know is true because the narration said "not all of them are always present". In that case the smallest gathering they've ever had must be 1 or 2 (because there is no "the smaller" of 4 and 4). But would a knight say "*even* fewer" if this is the largest possible gathering? He would need to be a somewhat mischievous sort of knight ...

---

On the other hand this analysis means that Harry must be *right* when he says "we are not 11", which makes everything inconsistent. Can a knave utter a *comma splice* between two statements of which one is true and the other is a lie?

Comment: Henning Makholm can you please explain the below "If the number is 2 modulo 4, then one of Harry and Jason is a knight and the other is a knave. But that is impossible since each of them claims a number that is not 2 modulo 4"?

Comment: @Sal.Cognato: Harry and Jason are _directly opposite each other_, so if there are $n$ people in total, then there are $n/2$ spaces between Harry and Jason. Now if $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$ then $n/2$ is an _odd_ number, and therefore Harry and Jason are _different kinds_. And therefore either 11 or 12 must be right. But neither 11 nor 12 is 2 modulo 4.

Comment: There are only $16$ inhabitants of the island and not everyone is present at this meeting, so $16$ is ruled out.

Comment: @DavidK: That information was added to the story after I answered.

Comment: @HenningMakholm you missed it because I just added it!! :) Sorry, my initial wording didn't make this clear enough, so I had to add this clarification.

Comment: I think the original wording was completely consistent with all inhabitants being present at the meeting described in the question, so this was more than a "clarification"; this or some other additional information was required to make the solution unique.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Referring to your last paragraph, I believe that NOT(A and B) = NOT A or NOT B which means that if we assume that Brandon is a liar and his statement consists of two sub-statements A and B, then this translates to NOT A or NOT B, which means that one sub-statement can be true and the other a lie. What do you think?

Comment: @WangXiuYingZhang: The usual assumption in knights-and-knaves puzzles seems to be that every _complete sentence_ a knave says must be a lie. So since Brandon's two utterances are complete sentences separated by an exclamation sign, this convention would mean they have to have the same truth value. The problem with _Harry's_ line is how to apply this convention in case of a comma splice, because it is (depending on who argues) neither two independent sentences nor a single grammatical sentence.

Comment: I think that 12 is also a plausible candidate. Here’s my reasoning:- Firstly, we know that the total number of people can’t be 2 mod 4 and also, they have to be even. So, the only possible candidates are 8 and 12 because 16 is not possible. Justifying the candidacy of 12, It can be possible that Janson is a Knight. The reason is that at the end of his part, Harry says that apparently you don’t know how to count which because he is speaks the truth in this case is the truth. So, it would be wrong to assume that Harry is a lier ignoring the possibility that he actually doesn’t know how to count.

Comment: (Well, it should have been”... it would be wrong to assume that **Janson** is a lier” in the previous comment). There is a problem in both cases: 8 as well as 12. Comma slice problem in the case of 8 and in the case of 12, Brandon can be assigned any position (of knight as well as of knave) which again generates inconsistency.

Comment: @HardikKalra: If Harry _actually_ doesn't know how to count, then no matter if he is a knight or a knave he would have needed to stay silent about numbers, because he wouldn't be able to guarantee that he was following his kind's absolute commandment to speak only truth, or only falsehoods. (Note that the story explicitly specifies that knights _always tell the truth_, not that they always say what they _think_ is the truth but are capable of being mistaken).

Comment: (First of all, I guess you meant Janson because that’s what I meant) But then, why does Harry blame Janson of not knowing how to count? This has to mean something in context with the question. Harry’s comment upon Janson strongly restricts us from throwing the attribute of Knave at him. Don’t you think so?

Comment: @HardikKalra: I don't see what you think is a problem here. Harry and Jason are both knaves. They both know how to count (so they can be sure that their claims of being 11 and 12 are lies). When Harry claims that Jason _doesn't_ know how to count, that is merely one of the lies that Harry, being knave, is obliged to tell.

Comment: That’s the reason I said both answers seem correct. If we take the possibility of 12 being correct, the excuse that Harry may not know how to count seems valid and everything else fits in nicely. But, yet again, the problems in both the cases (of 8 and of 12) do come back to me.